# ValueError: cannot determine region size; use 4-item box

Tags: image, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have tried to create a collage from an image list with 9 RGB images in it. I am getting ValueError: cannot determine region size; use 4-item box.
below is the function. what am I doing wrong?

```
def create_collage(width, height, imageList):
    cols = 3
    rows = 3
    thumbnail_width = width//cols
    thumbnail_height = height//rows
    size = thumbnail_width, thumbnail_height
    new_im = Image.new('RGB', (width, height))
    ims = []
    for image in imageList:
        th = image.thumbnail(size)
        ims.append(th)
    i = 0
    x = 0
    y = 0
    for col in range(cols):
        for row in range(rows):
            print(i, x, y)
            new_im.paste(ims[i], (x, y))
            i += 1
            y += thumbnail_height
        x += thumbnail_width
        y = 0

    new_im.save("Collage.png")
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the below code, it works perfectly fine.

#Ceating 3 x 3 Collage:

```
def getSize(imageList):
    for image in imageList:
        img_width, img_height = image.size
    return img_width, img_height


def createCollage(imageList, frame_width, images_per_row):

    img_width, img_height = getSize(imageList)

    #scaling factor
    sf = (frame_width-(images_per_row-1))/(images_per_row*img_width)

    scaled_img_width = ceil(img_width*sf)
    scaled_img_height = ceil(img_height*sf)

    number_of_rows = ceil(len(imageList)/images_per_row)
    frame_height = ceil(sf*img_height*number_of_rows) 

    new_im = Image.new('RGB', (frame_width, frame_height))

    i,j=0,0
    for num, im in enumerate(imageList):
        if num%images_per_row==0:
            i=0
        
        #resizing opened image
        im.thumbnail((scaled_img_width,scaled_img_height))
        #Iterate through a 3 x 3 grid
        y_cord = (j//images_per_row)*scaled_img_height
        new_im.paste(im, (i,y_cord))
        # print(i, y_cord)
        i=(i+scaled_img_width)
        j+=1

    # # new_im.show()
    new_im.save("collage.png", "PNG")
```